# Split String by , or + if not within " " or ' '

Tags: regex, perl

I have been trying to split a `string` by `,` OR `+` IF `,` or `+` are NOT within `" "` or `' '`.

Example:

`print var1,  "hello ,you "+var2`

Result

`print var1`

`hello ,you`

`var2`

I've been trying to come with a `regex` for this but haven't really gotten very far...

I've started with something like this:

```
(?:,|\+)\s*(?=(?:['"].*['"]))
```

but haven't figured out how to cover other cases.

Is it possible to split a `string` based on two values and get a result like what I am looking for?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regex like:

```
my @words = $line =~ /( (?:[^,+"']+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+ )/xg;
```

But it'd likely be much cleaner to use [`Text::ParseWords`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords;

my $line = 'print var1,  "hello ,you "+var2';

my @words = parse_line( qr{,\s*|\+}, 0, $line );

use Data::Dump;
dd @words;
```

Outputs:

```
("print var1", "hello ,you ", "var2")
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could do this using backtracking verbs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $re = qr/(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*F)|[,+]\s*/;

my $str = 'print var1,  "hello ,you "+var2';
my @res = split($re, $str);

print Dumper \@res;
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'print var1',
          '"hello ,you "',
          'var2'
        ];
```

Comment: can you explain the use of `SKIP` `F` and how it works ?